# Periodically fetch data and display it with Django

Tags: django, daemon, django-notification

I would like to implement a kind of "real-time" notification system in my Django application.

I would store some messages destined to a specific user in my database.
When a user is logged in the application, if there is a notification for him in the database, then the application displays it using the messages framework.
When he clicks on the message, it is deleted from the database.

I am a bit stuck on the "fetch the data every minute" thing. I heard of celery (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/#), but I would like to be sure it is the way to go there before diving in, because it seems a bit complicated to set up and use.

If there is an easy way to daemonise a django fonction, or if something similar to what I want to do already exist, I would appreciate any hint !

Comment: In a word: Ajax. Define some view method for that specific task and call it within the javascript client code with Ajax. That's a simple way to get you started.

Comment: And how do you call this method periodically ? I'm not exactly an Ajax expert

Comment: And other question, wouldn't this solution slow down a lot my application ?

Comment: Actually, there are two ways of _daemonizing_ an internet app. *Ajax* (most common one) and recently *WebSockects* (which is not yet full supported by all browsers). Ajax works like _polling_. That means, querying your web server each minute. That's how Facebook works for instance. If is just a simple task then it would be very easy to set up. I'll write an answer to guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is just a simple task, you may do with Ajax.

Just declare one URL for the ajax query:

```
#urls.py

...
url(r'^ajax/my_query$', my_app.views.ajax_processor)
...
```

then in your `my_app/views.py`:

```
#views.py

def ajax_processor(request):

    ... do the processing you want as if it is a normal web request.
    ... like querying the database
    ... you can return a `json` dictionary 
    ... or a normal `render_to_response` template with html
```

That should do on the server side. On the client side it would be lovely to use jQuery with the `$.ajax` function and do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/my_query',  // a normal get request
    success:function(data){  // success is the callback when the server responds
        /* if is json what you decided to return then process the json dict
           if is normal html render it wherver you want
        */
    }
});
```

Is just a simple set up, a bit of code in server-side and a bit of code in client-side.

If you are planning to develop a heavily real-time based application then you should rely on a better library, but if you only need to do a little query asynchronous then you may consider this way.

[Here is a good and simple ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) provided by the W3Schools to help you understand Ajax, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example) you can find useful information about polling with ajax/jquery.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the details, I think I'll try that before trying celery. I guess my function should be simple enough to be handled by ajax.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a link to an ajax tutorial to help you a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options to consider:

- [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Yes, it's not that trivial to set up, but it's very easy to configure and use from your python/django side via [django-celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/). Also take a look at celery [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).
- [rq](http://python-rq.org/) (Redis Queue). Simple job queue that is easy to set up.
- [django-cronograph](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/). Creating and running cron jobs easily from admin commands.

Also see:

- [Examples of Django and Celery: Periodic Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224482/examples-of-django-and-celery-periodic-tasks)
- [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: Thank you for the links ! I'll check them out as soon as possible :)

Comment: for me, i only need the server to do some stuff periodically, i think this suits me better. Thanks, @alecexe